# Movie with red/orange mist cloud that swallows people and kills them

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember my parents watching this as a kid and I have a vague memory of it, I remember seeing it at the HMV store so it does exist... should have written the name down.

From what I recall, there is a team of people who go to a moon base or a Mars base or something like that (the base might have been in a crater) which has multiple floors with stairs and ladders and so on all around the outside.

This takes place in the future and a red or orange fog/mist/cloud is attacking them. It seems to swallow people and they die. They have special guns (possibly electric beam shooting) that can push the fog back. I think it's an alien life form but it does look like a mist/cloud.

This would have come out sometime between 1995 and 2004, if I were to narrow it down 1998 and 2002.

Comment: Are you sure it's around 2000? I vaguely remember a really old sci-fi movie like this, maybe even black and white old. Terrible special effects. The space suit guys are shooting electrical arc guns at a cloud. Not much help, I know.

Comment: Ya no it definitely wasn't black and white, my parents rented it from a video store and i was only 8 or 10 at the time so it was definitely around 2000. Thanks tho :P ive been looking for years...

Comment: Could be a colorized _The Temp..._, er, _Forbidden Planet_.  http://imdb.com/title/tt0049223/ Video stores did, after all, also rent _old_ movies.

Comment: Forbidden Planet was originally in color.

Comment: Definitely not forbidden planet, the orange alien thing was CGI it was definitely in a time after the 80s

Answer (score 4):

I think parts of Ghosts of Mars ticks quite some of the boxes you mention:

- Obviously it takes place on Mars and there are bases/outposts.
- There is a team of people, a cross between police and military if memory serves me right, that investigates an outpost on Mars.
- The movie is from 2001, within your probable time window.
- Some archeologists or miners opened a tunnel from which a red cloud escapes. This cloud consists of alien ghosts/alien life forms. While this fog does not eat people, it transforms them into zombies. So here it differs from your recollection and perhaps the actual movie you are thinking of. I seem to recall though that it might look like they disappeared in the beginning, because all the zombies are traveling to some central place.
- I also seem to recall that perhaps electricity can expel a possessing ghost or something like that, but I would have to review the movie to confirm that.

There are some well known actors in it, like Ice Cube and Jason Statham. It was made by John Carpenter. So the presence of zombies should be no surprise.

Answer (score 4):

Hey man this bugged me for years, but I figured it out finally! It's a horrible movie called **Final Fantasy** *The Spirits Within*. Came out in 2001

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if it explained more about the matching points.  E.g. is it a Moon base or a Mars base or something else?  Is the fog/mist/cloud an alien life form?  Can you link or include images so that people can compare?  Consider the possibility that you are thinking of a different movie than the poster was.  (Yes, there could be two movies set in space where people are killed by a red/orange mist.)